# 4g connection with RPi3 and dongle

Tags: modem

I have a RPi 3 and a Huawei E397 usb dongle with a Ting SIM card; I'm trying to have the Pi itself connect to the internet automatically on startup.

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.emnify.com/2015/06/18/how-to-fit-a-raspberry-pi-with-mobile-connectivity/) but with the APN replaced with Ting's APN "wholesale". I am running into problems:

- The connection is not automatic; on startup the dongle will just continually try to register to the 4g network but won't actually connect until I log in and run `sudo ifup gprs`. Even adding that command in `/etc/rc.local` doesn't seem to work. `wvdial` seems to have the same limitation. How do I work around this?
- Even when I do connect manually, the connection will stay connected for a couple minutes, then disconnect and reconnect for no reasons (`/var/log/syslog` shows `pppd` hangup and `SIGHUP`). I'm not sure if this is a power limitation; if the Pi's USB port isn't providing enough power and I'd have to buy a powered USB hub for it to work; are there other possibilities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make sure your LTE modem is detected by system and switched by usb_modeswitch to modem mode prior to run ppp script. I, personally, use modem availability check (like described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd), see **Patch for modem availability after booting** part
- I have the same problem - Pi loses modem after couple of mins of activity. Suspect it's power issues as well .Did you try to use powered hub? Did it fix the problem?

**Update!!!***
Tip that eventually worked for my E397 modem with no additional powered hub:  when modem is detected in system and switched by modeswitch to modem mode, make sure you use serial port which is mapped to  **PCUI** interface among these which belong to modem, this one  is usually second serial (or ttyUSB1). You may check needed by running serial terminal to modem and issuing **AT^SETPORT?**  which gives you current configuration (modem reply would be smth like A1,A2;1,2,3,7,A1,A2 - check the part after semicolon) and **AT^SETPORT=?** which lists available options. Google for details. Once again, use PCUI, not MODEM port in your dial-up script.

Comment: A powered hub didn't seem to fix the problem sadly :/ we just ended up asking someone in the area (since this was a IoT kinda project) if we could use their wifi. saves us the monthly data cost too :D but we're at their whim now.

Comment: See update, solution is found!